# my mouseover and my function goes out does not work

Tags: javascript, sorting, onmouseover

I have two problems and it's been hours that I try to fix them without success.
Firstly For a game that I am creating, I have to make appear the "div" of the date when I pass the mouse over the "div" of the name of the player.
it may be useful for me to specify that these "divs" are created in an inner.HTML and then I store them in the localStorage.
Secondly, I want to rank the players in order of score (the best to be in position 1) with the method 'sort'. But my method doesn't work.
thank you for your help.

```
function displayDate(){
    if(dom.theDate.style.display == "none"){
    dom.theDate.style.display = "inline-block";
    }else {
        dom.theDate.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function createHSHTML() {
    toAppend = '';
    arr.forEach(function (player, i) {
        toAppend += ` <div id="player">
                <div id="theDate" style = "display:none">(${dateText})</div>
                <div id="playerScore" style = "display:inline-block">${player.rankedScore} -</div>
                <div onmouseover = "displayDate()" id = "playerName" style = "display:inline-block">${player.rankedName}<br></div>  
                </div>`;
    })
    dom.players.innerHTML = toAppend;
}

arr.sort((a, b) => (b.player.rankedScore) - (a.player.rankedScore));
```

Answer (score 1):

**For your first problem :**

The [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) required the ID attribute to be unique in a page:

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique
>   in a document.

If you have several elements with the same ID, your HTML **is not valid**.

So you can concatenate the iterator 'i' of your forEach loop with the name you want for the ids of your divs (something like "player$(i)").

Then, you will have multiple options to retrieve the name of the right div when you call the function `displayDate()` you can pass the 'i' to the function so you will know which div you need to edit, something like :

```
function displayDate(i){
    ...
}

<div onmouseover = "displayDate($(i))"...
```

And please use `document.getElementById("myDiv")`

**Second problem :**

For me, something like that : `arr.sort(function(a, b){return a.rankedScore - b.rankedScore});`
do the job!

Comment: First thanks  for your answer. I used a single name by id. And I also used the "document.getElementById (" myDiv ")" I simply put them in a const (object) named "dom" so that it is easier for me to find and reread. I did not put all the code. Here they are :
const dom = {
     players: document.getElementById ("players"),
     theDate: document.getElementById ("theDate"),
     player: document.getElementById ('player'),
     playerName: document.getElementById ("playerName"),
     playerScore: document.getElementById ("playerScore")
}
Your function "sort" works very well thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear it!

Comment: @Yaël if my answer solve your issue you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Ok i understood the problem of the id and the class . Thank you everything works now .